# Bootstrap Carousel Previous and Next image instead of blank background

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I refer all the previous questions like which i need. But I didn't get it proper answer. For this link first example http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp instead of blank previous and next is it possible to display previous and next image. I expected answer comes like this https://in.bookmyshow.com/bengaluru/movies can anybody help please

Comment: Put some more time in writing your question and we will put more time in the answer :)

Comment: Did you mean I have to explain more about this questions?

Comment: Yes, you simply refer to some simular questions. Explain clearly what you are trying to achive, what you tried to achieve that and where you are stuck. Show some code so we can correct you or show you the right direction.